# Render value from ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular

I have a function that takes the size of a given div and does some calculation. I cannot do it in the OnInit because the div is not rendered yet. In ngAfterViewChecked I get the correct size and do the calculation, but cannot display it on the screen because the initial value is 0 (probably because the calculation takes place after the initialization and the value is 0). My question is: how can I render the value that is set in ngAfterViewChecked? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

[ngAfterViewChecked](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked) is called after every change detection. You probably need [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) if you would like to do the calculation one time and not for every check. If you give us a minimal repro then I can edit my answer to be more exact.

Comment: I've tried ngAfterViewInit as well, but did not work either. What do you minimal repro? Only ngAfterViewChecked retrieved the right size of the div because everything was rendered for the calculation, I don't know why is this happening. ngAfterViewInit should be the right thing to use.